# Separating a String into columns

Tags: sql-server

I have this string of data in date order that each update is separated by a comma - I would like to separate each update into its' own column.

This is the substring I am using to get the current result:

```
` , substring(
  (  
  select ','+ (left([Equipment_Status_Type_CD],4) +' '+cast(Cast([Equipment_Status_System_TS] as date) as varchar)+' '+cast(Cast([Equipment_Status_System_TS]as time(0))as varchar)) as [text()] 
  
  from DBO cte with (nolock) 
  left Join  DBO2 f with(nolock)  on Statusing_Facility_CD = f.Facility_CD
  where cte.[Equipment_Unit_NB] =cte2.[Equipment_Unit_NB] and [Equipment_Status_System_TS] between '2020-12-28' and '2021-01-03'
order by [Equipment_Unit_NB], Equipment_Status_System_TS asc
for xml path ('')
  
 ),1,800)[TenderStringDateTime]`
```

Full Query to Reference - not sure where to make the edit suggested so hopefully this will leave nothing to question:`

```
With Cte as (
SELECT [Standard_Carrier_Alpha_CD]
      ,[Equipment_Unit_NB]
      ,cast([Equipment_Status_System_TS]as varchar) as Equipment_Status_System_TS
      ,[Equipment_Status_Type_CD]
      ,[Statusing_Facility_CD]
      ,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by concat( [Standard_Carrier_Alpha_CD],'',[Equipment_Unit_NB]) order by Equipment_Status_System_TS desc) Ranking 

  FROM dbo.DILKOPS.[Equipment_Status] with (nolock)
  left join dbo.DILKOPS.[Facility] f on [Statusing_Facility_CD] = f.Facility_CD
  


  ),
  
  Cte2 as  
  (SELECT  [Standard_Carrier_Alpha_CD]
      ,[Equipment_Unit_NB]
      ,[Spot_Type_CD]       
      ,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by concat( [Standard_Carrier_Alpha_CD],'',[Equipment_Unit_NB]) order by [Create_TS] desc) Ranking2
       
  FROM dbo.DILKOPS.[Trailer_Spot]

  ),
  
  Cte3 as
   (Select Distinct 
   Case when Cte.[Standard_Carrier_Alpha_CD] <> 'rdwy' then  concat( Cte.[Standard_Carrier_Alpha_CD],'',Cte.[Equipment_Unit_NB]) else Cte.[Equipment_Unit_NB] end Trailer_Number
  --,f.Division_CD
  --,f.Area_CD
  --,[Statusing_Facility_CD]
  --,[Equipment_Status_System_TS] As Status_Time
  ,[Primary_Use_NM]
  ,[Equipment_Exterior_Length_QT]
  --, Equipment_Status_Type_CD
  


  , substring(
  (  
  select ','+ (left([Equipment_Status_Type_CD],4) +' '+cast(Cast([Equipment_Status_System_TS] as date) as varchar)+' '+cast(Cast([Equipment_Status_System_TS]as time(0))as varchar)) as [text()] ---+ cast(Equipment_Status_System_TS as varchar)
  
  from dbo.DILKOPS.[Equipment_Status]cte with (nolock) 
  left Join  dbo.DILKOPS.[Facility] f with(nolock)  on Statusing_Facility_CD = f.Facility_CD
 -- left join [DILAKE].[MFD].[EQP_EQP_SPOT_DTL] a WITH (NOLOCK) on a.[EQP_SPOT_ORZ_RFRNC_CD] = f.Facility_CD

  where cte.[Equipment_Unit_NB] =cte2.[Equipment_Unit_NB] and [Equipment_Status_System_TS] between '2020-12-28' and '2021-01-03'
order by [Equipment_Unit_NB], Equipment_Status_System_TS asc
for xml path ('')
  
 ),1,800)[TenderStringDateTime]




, substring ((  
  select ','+ (left([Equipment_Status_Type_CD],4))  as [text()] ---+ cast(Equipment_Status_System_TS as varchar)
  
  from dbo.DILKOPS.[Equipment_Status]cte with (nolock) 

  where cte.[Equipment_Unit_NB] =cte2.[Equipment_Unit_NB] and [Equipment_Status_System_TS] between '2020-11-30' and '2020-12-11' --and  Equipment_Status_Type_CD in ('cltg','spt','ofd','SU','SE') 

order by [Equipment_Unit_NB], Equipment_Status_System_TS asc
for xml path ('')
  
 ),1,500) TenderStringCode

 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  


  from Cte
  Left Join Cte2 on cte.[Standard_Carrier_Alpha_CD] = cte2.[Standard_Carrier_Alpha_CD] and  cte.[Equipment_Unit_NB] =cte2.[Equipment_Unit_NB]
  Left Join dbo.DILKOPS.[Equipment] a  with (nolocK) on cte.[Standard_Carrier_Alpha_CD] = a.[Standard_Carrier_Alpha_CD] and  cte.[Equipment_Unit_NB] =a.[Equipment_Unit_NB]
  Left Join dbo.DILKOPS.[Facility] b  with (nolocK) on [Statusing_Facility_CD] =[Facility_CD] 
  Left Join  dbo.DILKOPS.[Facility] f with(nolock)  on Statusing_Facility_CD = f.Facility_CD
  Left Join dbo.DILKMFD.[EQP_EQP_SPOT_DTL] dt WITH (NOLOCK) on dt.[EQP_SPOT_ORZ_RFRNC_CD] = f.Facility_CD


  Where ranking = 1 
  and Ranking2 = 1
  and [Fenced_Not_Avbl_IN] <> 'y'
  and [Emergency_Repair_Due_IN] <> 'y'
  and [Spot_Type_CD] <> 'CONV'
  and Equipment_Status_Type_CD <> ('%CPU%') 
  and a.[Standard_Carrier_Alpha_CD] = 'RDWY'
)



Select  top 100
* 


-----------------Trailer Tender Count for Date Range----------------------------------------
,(LEN(TenderStringCode+'.') - LEN(REPLACE(TenderStringCode+'.', 'SPT', ''))) / len('SPT') as SPT
,(LEN(TenderStringCode+'.') - LEN(REPLACE(TenderStringCode+'.', 'SE', ''))) / len('SE') as SE
,(LEN(TenderStringCode+'.') - LEN(REPLACE(TenderStringCode+'.', 'SL', ''))) / len('SL') as SL
,(LEN(TenderStringCode+'.') - LEN(REPLACE(TenderStringCode+'.', 'SU', ''))) / len('SU') as SU
,(LEN(TenderStringCode+'.') - LEN(REPLACE(TenderStringCode+'.', 'LDD', ''))) / len('LDD') as LDD
,(LEN(TenderStringCode+'.') - LEN(REPLACE(TenderStringCode+'.', 'LDG', ''))) / len('LDG') as LDG
,((LEN(TenderStringCode+'.') - LEN(REPLACE(TenderStringCode+'.', 'CL', ''))) / len('CL')) - ((LEN(TenderStringCode+'.') - LEN(REPLACE(TenderStringCode+'.', 'CLTG', ''))) / len('CLTG')) as CL
,(LEN(TenderStringCode+'.') - LEN(REPLACE(TenderStringCode+'.', 'CLTG', ''))) / len('CLTG') as CLTG
,(LEN(TenderStringCode+'.') - LEN(REPLACE(TenderStringCode+'.', 'MTY', ''))) / len('MTY') as MTY
,(LEN(TenderStringCode+'.') - LEN(REPLACE(TenderStringCode+'.', 'OFD', ''))) / len('OFD') as OFD
,(LEN(TenderStringCode+'.') - LEN(REPLACE(TenderStringCode+'.', 'ENR', ''))) / len('ENR') as ENR
,(LEN(TenderStringCode+'.') - LEN(REPLACE(TenderStringCode+'.', 'ARR', ''))) / len('ARR') as ARR
,(LEN(TenderStringCode+'.') - LEN(REPLACE(TenderStringCode+'.', 'ARV', ''))) / len('ARV') as ARV
,(LEN(TenderStringCode+'.') - LEN(REPLACE(TenderStringCode+'.', 'UAD', ''))) / len('UAD') as UAD
,(LEN(TenderStringCode+'.') - LEN(REPLACE(TenderStringCode+'.', 'BOR', ''))) / len('BOR') as BOR
,(LEN(TenderStringCode+'.') - LEN(REPLACE(TenderStringCode+'.', 'CPU', ''))) / len('CPU') as CPU


From Cte3 `
```

Current Result: `

```
,LDG 2020-12-29 16:07:41,LDD 2020-12-29 16:45:17,ENR 2020-12-29 17:14:32,ARR 2020-12-29 22:17:55,ENR 2020-12-30 22:51:09
```

Preferred Result:

```
Rank1                             Rank2                       Rank3
LDG 2020-12-29 16:07:41          LDD 2020-12-29 16:45:17     ENR 2020-12-29 17:14:32
```

Comment: How many `Rank` do you have maximum? Is it a fixed number?

Comment: You already *have* the data as separate values - why is the first part of your solution "I'll push all of these values into a single string so that now I have to pull that apart too"?

Comment: It is not a fixed number of ranks @Charlieface

Comment: That is the original substring - trying to figure out how to avoid doing the substring and just put the updates in their individual columns rather than a string - just wanted to show what I was working with @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Then you will end up with hundreds, thousands of columns. Where does it stop? And please don't use `nolock`. Can you edit in the rest of your query?

Comment: Sorry - the max rank in this situation would be 14 columns. Any update after 14 occurrences would not be accounted for. Also, why shouldn't I use (nolock)? @Charlieface

Comment: See [@AaronBertrand](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) on `nolock`. I will give you a solution based on `row_number` in a moment if you post the full query

Comment: Can I message it to you? It is too long to comment it @Charlieface

Comment: Edit the question. You can skip most of the selects, I just need the joins and the primary keys

Comment: Full query is inserted now - thank you for your help @charlieface

Comment: You have a number of issues in your query: Is your database really called dbo or is that the schema name? This `Equipment_Status_Type_CD <> ('%CPU%') ` should probably be `NOT LIKE`? Don't alias a table `as cte` if it is not a cte, or did you mean to join `cte` anyway? `NOLOCK` and brackets everywhere? Specify `varchar(length)`. Don't know what these do but doesn't look right `LEN(TenderStringCode+'.')...` I think it doesn't do what think it does. `partition by concat(` etc should just be `partition by (Standard_Carrier_Alpha_CD, Equipment_Unit_NB)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edited for actual query*

You need to number each row, then pivot on the row number.

In `cte3` you need to add an `APPLY` after the joins

```sql
CROSS APPLY
(
  select
      TenderStringDateTime,
      TenderStringCode,
      [1] as Rank1,
      [2] as Rank2,
      [3] as Rank3,
      [4] as Rank4,
      [5] as Rank5,
      [6] as Rank6,
      [7] as Rank7,
      [8] as Rank8,
      [9] as Rank9,
      [10] as Rank10,
      [11] as Rank11,
      [12] as Rank12,
      [13] as Rank13,
      [14] as Rank14    
  from (

    select
      left(Equipment_Status_Type_CD, 4) +
        ' ' +
        convert(varchar(20), Equipment_Status_System_TS as date, 120))
      as TenderStringDateTime,
      left(Equipment_Status_Type_CD], 4) as TenderStringCode,
      row_number() over(order by Equipment_Unit_NB, Equipment_Status_System_TS) as rn

    from dbo.DILKOPS.Equipment_Status cte
    left Join  dbo.DILKOPS.Facility f on Statusing_Facility_CD = f.Facility_CD
    where cte.Equipment_Unit_NB = cte2.Equipment_Unit_NB and
       Equipment_Status_System_TS between '2020-12-28' and '2021-01-03'
  ) as ranking

  pivot( min(ranking.txt) for ranking.rn in
    ([1],[2],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14])
  ) as pvt
) as ranking
```

Now in the select of `cte3`, instead of the two subqueries, you can just add `ranking.*`